# Read a file with comments in first 10 lines

Tags: r, csv

I currently have a txt file that contains instructions in the first 10 rows followed by comma separated values. I would like to read this file in R but am not sure how since there are essentially two parts to the file with different structure.

I currently pre-process the file in Python but was wondering if there was a way to avoid this and only do it in R?

sample:

```
This is a row containing instructions

 Here is another one

 More instructions

date,dollar_amount,zip_code
2014-10-01,43.33,93210
2014-10-01,42.00,94612
```

Edit:
I wouldn't mind a suggestion on how to do this in Python if doing the whole thing in Python is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just do (in R)

```
read.table("yourfile.txt", skip=10, header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

where skip indicates how many lines at the start of the file to ignore